# Restricting access to an in-use disk on Solaris

Tags: solaris, storage

I have two identical servers (Running Solaris) connected to a Sun Storedge 3100 through SCSI.
I want to make a cluster out of them. The storage will be used to store a database.

The Storage works fine when I connect it to just one server, but when I connect it to both servers it starts to perform very badly. It takes 20 minutes to display the format output, and even then it sees some disks as unformatted. This may be due to the fact that both servers are trying to access the same disks at the same time.

Is there a way to restrict access to in-use disks? From what I've heard there should be a software that comes with Solaris that does this, but I have not been able to find details about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Normally you'd install something like Sun Cluster. If you want to use something else, then as a start make sure that each server (initiator) has a unique SCSI ID, otherwise things get very confused. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19787-01/819-2969/x-17eg5/index.html

Comment: Did you changed `scsi-initiator-id`? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19787-01/819-2995/installationtemplate-65/index.html says how to do it (look at item 5).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - you **really** need to use a cluster framework of some sort in order to have any guarantee regarding data integrity.

When it comes to enabling multi-node access to shared storage, HA-ZFS is great, HA-SVM is good if you can't do ZFS, VxVM is also good (make sure you check the licensing first).

Did I mention you need to use a cluster framework? Yeah - do that. Don't run the risk of losing your data due to skimping on a framework which will guard against that problem.